Refresh all linked libraries with the press of a button?
I work a lot with linked .blend files, and doing the back and forth between scenes could be so much smoother if I could just refresh linked libraries with a keyboard shortcut instead of having to change my Outliner menu, find the right library, and click refresh.
I found this addon which is supposed to always automatically refresh libraries as soon as it detects a change, but I would rather have control over when libraries refresh, rather than it happening automatically.
Does anyone know how I could do this ? Maybe a python script ?
Thanks a lot !

I don't know about an alternative method for this, but you always can split the outliner in two: one with 'view layer' display mode and the other with 'blender file'.

